# Find closest match to input string in a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have problems finding an implementation of closest match strings for .net

I would like to match a list of strings, example:

input string: "Publiczna Szkoła Podstawowa im. Bolesława Chrobrego w Wąsoszu"

List of strings:

Publiczna Szkoła Podstawowa im. B. Chrobrego w Wąsoszu

Szkoła Podstawowa Specjalna

Szkoła Podstawowa im.Henryka Sienkiewicza w Wąsoszu

Szkoła Podstawowa im. Romualda Traugutta w Wąsoszu Górnym

This would clearly need to be matched with "Publiczna Szkoła Podstawowa im. B. Chrobrego w Wąsoszu".

What algorithms are there available for .net?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_distance)

> Edit distance is a way of quantifying how dissimilar two strings
>   (e.g., words) are to one another by counting the minimum number of
>   operations required to transform one string into the other.

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

> Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum
>   number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or
>   substitutions) required to change one word into the other.

[Fast, memory efficient Levenshtein algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm)

[C# Levenshtein](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)

```
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Contains approximate string matching
/// </summary>
static class LevenshteinDistance
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compute the distance between two strings.
    /// </summary>
    public static int Compute(string s, string t)
    {
    int n = s.Length;
    int m = t.Length;
    int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

    // Step 1
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
    {
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
    {
    }

    // Step 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        //Step 4
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
        // Step 5
        int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

        // Step 6
        d[i, j] = Math.Min(
            Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
            d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    // Step 7
    return d[n, m];
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(LevenshteinDistance.Compute("aunt", "ant"));
    Console.WriteLine(LevenshteinDistance.Compute("Sam", "Samantha"));
    Console.WriteLine(LevenshteinDistance.Compute("flomax", "volmax"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Very fast! Your code's results validated 100% against my implementation, but yours ran 2x faster than what I came up with.

Comment: Does this work with comparing sentences with spaces and special characters?

Answer (score 24):

.NET does not supply anything out of the box - you need to implement a an [*Edit Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm yourself. For example, you can use [*Levenshtein Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), like this:

```
// This code is an implementation of the pseudocode from the Wikipedia,
// showing a naive implementation.
// You should research an algorithm with better space complexity.
public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t) {
    int n = s.Length;
    int m = t.Length;
    int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];
    if (n == 0) {
        return m;
    }
    if (m == 0) {
        return n;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
        ;
    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
       ;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
            d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    return d[n, m];
}
```

Call `LevenshteinDistance(targetString, possible[i])` for each `i`, then pick the string `possible[i]` for which `LevenshteinDistance` returns the smallest value.

Comment: This just finds the closest in length to the given string. If i pass part of the word to a list of strings, it will choose the one that is closest in length rather than the one that has the actual string.

Comment: @Ali123 Wrong: this algorithm finds the closest string by **edit distance**, not by length. If you do not understand what this means, there is a link at the top of the answer to help you.

Comment: I tried it with an option that has the actual keyword that i am searching for but it ignored it and chose the shortest sentence. See this example where i used the fuzzySearch plugin which gave the highest value that i am looking for while the function you kindly provided choose the shortest string. https://dotnetfiddle.net/dy5rm5

Comment: @Ali123 Let's do it by hand: to go from "transcribe" to "ecm" you need to delete nine characters (t, r, a, n, s, c, r, i, and b) and then insert two more characters at the end (c and m), for a total score of 9+2 = 11. To go from "open form for ecm" to just "ecm" you need to delete everything before "ecm", which comes to 14 characters in total. 11 is lower than 14, so in terms of the edit distance "transcribe" wins.

Comment: i understand that. Your function works perfectly, but it's not suitable for my needs.  is "ECM" is closer to "Open form for ECM" than "transcribe" phonetically, which is what i needed in my case.  Levenshtein Distance might be sutiable for auto correction and other use cases. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ali123 Did you managed to advance into this point? I have a similar issue

Comment: @rd1218 i found a library that implement "Fuzzy Search" https://github.com/JakeBayer/FuzzySharp

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I had a similar requirement to @Ali123:

> "ECM" is closer to "Open form for ECM" than "transcribe" phonetically

I found a simple solution that works for my use case, which is comparing sentences, and finding the sentence that has the most words in common:

```
public static string FindBestMatch(string stringToCompare, IEnumerable<string> strs) {

    HashSet<string> strCompareHash = stringToCompare.Split(' ').ToHashSet();

    int maxIntersectCount = 0;
    string bestMatch = string.Empty;

    foreach (string str in strs)
    {
        HashSet<string> strHash = str.Split(' ').ToHashSet();

        int intersectCount = strCompareHash.Intersect(strHash).Count();

        if (intersectCount > maxIntersectCount)
        {
            maxIntersectCount = intersectCount;
            bestMatch = str;
        }
    }

    return bestMatch;
}
```